# SQL Query is not returning NULL values despite using IFNULL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a test table set up as such: [Table Rows setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXC2O.png)

My objective is to try and get the count of departments that were established before the current department. My SQL Is:

```
SELECT A.Department, IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) 
FROM Departments A
INNER JOIN Departments B ON B.YearOfEstablishment < A.YearOfEstablishment
GROUP BY Department
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

However I've tried both **`LEFT JOIN`** and **`INNER JOIN`**, the last department that was found first never is returned because I can assume it is null. Despite having `IFNULL`, the department is not shown.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is the query you need :

```
SELECT A.Department, COUNT(B.Department)
FROM Departments A
LEFT JOIN Departments B ON B.YearOfEstablishment < A.YearOfEstablishment
GROUP BY A.Department
ORDER BY 2;
```

See **[this db fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dLnHq8qoLs2qWwLPKkuMAL/3)**.

```
| Department        | cnt |
| ----------------- | --- |
| Office Management | 0   |
| Business          | 1   |
| Sales Management  | 2   |
| ComputerScience   | 3   |
| Liberal Arts      | 4   |
| Farming           | 4   |
| Communications    | 6   |
| Digital Science   | 7   |
```

NB : as commented by @fifonik, `IFNULL` is not needed since `COUNT` already returns `0` when no records are available.

Comment: You do not need to use IFNULL here as COUNT always return number.

Comment: @fifonik : correct, thanks for reminding me of that... I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can better do this using `rank()` or `row_number()`:

```
SELECT d.Department,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YearOfEstablishment) - 1 as seqnum
FROM Departments d
ORDER BY seqnum;
```

With no ties, this would be the same as your query.  It might be better to do:

```
SELECT d.Department,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YearOfEstablishment) - 1 as seqnum
FROM Departments d
ORDER BY seqnum;
```

This should be the count you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this:

```
SELECT
      A.Department
    , A.YearOfEstablishment
    , COUNT(*) - 1
FROM
    Departments A
    INNER JOIN Departments B ON (
           A.id = B.id
        OR B.YearOfEstablishment < A.YearOfEstablishment
    )
GROUP BY
    Department
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*);
```